# FileInputStream vs ClassPathResource vs getResourceAsStream and file integrity

Tags: java, stream, apache-poi

I have a weird problem :

in src/main/resources i have a "template.xlsx" file.

If i do this :

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("template.xlsx").getInputStream();
```

Or this :

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("template.xlsx");
```

Or this :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/template.xlsx");
```

When i try to create a workbook :

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
```

I get this error :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
```

BUT, when i get my file like this :

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/.../src/main/resources/template.xlsx");
```

It works !

What is wrong ? I can't hardcode the fullpath to the file.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure that when you load from the classpath you are *completely* sure which version of `template.xlsx` is being loaded? A `getResourceAsStream()` (and the like) can load a resource from many places. With the filename you are absolutely sure what is being loaded.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue, you probably have a problem with maven filtering.

This code load the file from source, unfiltered

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/.../src/main/resources/template.xlsx");
```

This code load the file from the target directory, after maven has filtered the content

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/template.xlsx");
```

You should not filter binary files like excel and use two mutually exclusive resource sets as described at the bottom of this page [maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: This is due to maven filtering and not the method used to load the stream ! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer , I have spent so many hours on this  problem ((

Comment: How to exclude from filtering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477961/2387977

Answer (score 0):

haven't you try accessing it like

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/main/resources/template.xlsx");
```

?