# read excel file(which is in classpath ) via apache poi

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, classpath

I am trying to read (using apache poi) .xlsx file  which is not in file system but in classpath. I am using maven - so it is in resources folder.

my code is -

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = MyReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(resourceAsStream);
```

I am getting this exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
        at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:297) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:121) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:51) ~[poi
a3]
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:88) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11-beta3.jar:3.11-beta3]
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11-beta3.jar:3.11-beta3]
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37) ~[poi-ooxml-3.11-beta3.jar:3.11-beta3]
```

When I read same file from file system everything is fine. 
Is there a bug in my code or do I miss understand something?

UPDATE1:  This is in web app, so code is deployed in tomcat 7.

UPDATE2:  when I read same file in this way - it works.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\.....\\test.xlsx");
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

 Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

thanks

Comment: How is the file getting into the resources folder / classpath? Are you sure that that process isn't corrupting it?

Comment: basically, it is in web app, so it deployed on Tomcat 7. I don't think that it gets corrupted. but if you have some thoughts please let me know.

Comment: Calculate the md5 hash of the file before deployment, and of the same file deployed in the webapp?

Comment: it is Oracle jdk1.7.0_51

Comment: @Gagravarr , Alex Richter I have updated question, could you please take a look, maybe it will help.

Comment: I still think there's a risk that your maven packaging is corrupting the file. Please calculate the md5 checksums of pre and post deployed files and confirm

Comment: @Gagravarr you were right, maven resource plugin corrupts  file, thank you very much for your help , I found the same question in other stackoverflow post and put it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spending days on this problem I found an answer in stackoverflow )).
[FileInputStream vs ClassPathResource vs getResourceAsStream and file integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840631/fileinputstream-vs-classpathresource-vs-getresourceasstream-and-file-integrity)

the problem in maven-resources-plugin filtering, it corrupts  excel file .

```
You should not filter binary files like excel and use two mutually exclusive resource sets as described at the bottom of this page
```

[maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Adding more information to @user1321466 answer, to filter you can do as described in maven resources plugin site:

> If you have both text files and binary files as resources it is
>   recommended to have two separated folders. One folder
>   src/main/resources (default) for the resources which are not filtered
>   and another folder src/main/resources-filtered for the resources which
>   are filtered.

or just exclude the files from filtering:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.xsd</exclude>
        <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.xsl</include>
        <include>**/*.xslx</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file at the top of the classpath, i.e. in WEB-INF/classes?

The API doc for Classloader.getResource() says the resource name is:

"The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource."

So if your file is in some subdirectory, that path should be part of the resource name.

Comment: file is in maven resources folder. and i am able to get InputStream. problem connected with apache poi api, I do not know why it doesn't  "like" stream and throw exception. but anyway thanks for answer