# Loading an excel(.xlsx/.xls) file from maven project resources folder (src/main/resources)

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, classpath

Here i am trying to load an excel file from resources folder(src/main/resources) of a maven project.

**Folder Structure**

```
MyWebApp
   |______src/main/java
   |           |____Test.java
   |
   |______src/main/resources
   |            |______test
   |                    |___hello.properties
   |                    |___template.xlsx
   |______target
            |___MyWebApp
                  |____WEB_INF
                         |___classes
                                |__test
                                     |__hello.properties
                                     |__template.xlsx
```

**My Approach**

```
//loading excel file
String resource = "/test/template.xlsx";
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource(resource) == null); // prints true

//loading properties file
String resource = "/test/hello.properties";
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource(resource) == null); //prints false

//I have also tried below methods
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource); //null
new ClassPathResource(resource).getInputStream(); //null
```

After doing some googling i came to know, [maven filters binary contents](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). To over come that i modified my `pom.xml` to allow `.xlsx`,`.xls` file extenstions not to be filtered with this [help](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

**pom.xml**

```
<configuration>                
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                 <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                     <includes>
                         <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
                         <include>**/*.xls</include>
                     </includes>
             </resource>
         </resources>
</configuration>
```

I could able to load the properties file, but i could not able to load the excel file by using above approach. From my side i referred the below two links ([Rererence-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387365/read-excel-filewhich-is-in-classpath-via-apache-poi),
[Reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840631/fileinputstream-vs-classpathresource-vs-getresourceasstream-and-file-integrity)) but no success. Please help me if you have some thoughts/ideas on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In [the maven documentation page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) which you've linked in your there is said:

> If you have both text files and binary files as resources it is
>   recommended to have **two separated folders**. One folder
>   src/main/resources (default) for the resources which are not filtered
>   and another folder src/main/resources-filtered for the resources which
>   are filtered.

So you should hold the properties and xlsx files in separate directories.

There is also an [information about excluding binary files from filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      ...
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: thanks Ulrich for your answer, Instead of having 2 different folders, i used `<include>**/*.xlsx</include>` to include my excel files. either we can have 2 folders or we can use `include'. and your option of excluding binary files i have already tried, still the same issue.

Comment: did you check if `template.xlsx` is contained in the jar file that is produced during `mvn package` ?

Comment: Yes, jar file contains the excel file

Comment: I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113891/maven-excel-resource-file)