# Corrupt Excel Maven

Tags: java, excel, maven, classloader, corrupt

I have some problems with Maven, Excel and poi package.
I access to an excel file thanks to the code :

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("src/main/resources/file.xlsx"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
```

This code works correctly and I can read data inside later in my code.
Instead of a "new File(..)", I have to use this code below to access resources in dev mode and once the jar is built.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
String path = classLoader.getResource(fileName).toURI().getPath();
```

The given path is in "target/classes" and Maven do a "copy" of this file into folder "myproject/target/classes" of the current project(perfect so).

However, the xslx file copied by Maven is corrupted and neither by using Excel software, I can't access to its content. The original file size is 500Kb, the copied file size is more than 1Mb. (All other files img,txt.. are well copied excepted the xslx files)

I done lots of searches, I could find some answers like :
[FileInputStream vs ClassPathResource vs getResourceAsStream and file integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840631/fileinputstream-vs-classpathresource-vs-getresourceasstream-and-file-integrity)
. I tried all solutions I could find but impossible to solve mine and I always get the same error :

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not open the specified zip entry source stream
```

Or

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.xlsx
```

From the same way of classLoader, I can access to my json, txt and image files.

Someone has answer on this issue ?
Why Maven doubles the size of the xlsx files and why they are corrupted ?
Any solution to solve that ? 
I need help

Comment: Without any further configuration, Maven should simply copy the file from src/main/resources to target/classes without modification. So there must be a Maven plugin configured which causes your behavior. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Something else is wrong here.  Please do the MCVE.